# Possible to render Material elements within material-table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm working on a data display for my application and have been looking into different available data table components built on top of Material UI. I'm wondering if it would be possible with `material-table` to render Material UI `<Chip>` components within one of the table columns. I tried what I thought made the most sense to attempt something like this, but it did not work. My attempt:

```
const test = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Chip>Test</Chip>
        <Chip>Another Test</Chip>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

And then trying to render it:

```
<MaterialTable
   columns={[
      { title: 'Project Types', field: 'types' }
   ]}
   data={[
      { types: test },
   ]}
/>
```

Is there anything I can do to render these Chips within my Material Table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?
Check out `MaterialTable`'s [custom column rendering section](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/custom-column-rendering)

```
<MaterialTable
  columns={[
    {
      title: 'Project Types',
      field: 'types',
      render: rowData => (
        <div>
          {rowData.types.map(type => (
            <Chip key={type} label={type}/>
          ))}
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ]}
/>;
```

Comment: You should replace the `name` and `id` parameters here `<Chip key={type.id}>{type.name}</Chip>` with the ones that you have stored in your types array. So if the type has a `title` instead of `name` it should be `{type.title}`. Try console logging what fields the types array has. If it's just a regular string array, you should simply output it as `{type}`

Comment: I am silly. I forgot that <Chip> components utilize the label={} to actually display text, and that they are self-closing elements. Thank you for your help. I've queued up a modification to your solution to reflect the syntactically correct code. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sure, just don't forget to add the `key={type}` as well if your types are unique, so you don't get warnings in your console output.